# Insertion by removing '000000' in the unix timestamp

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm inserting some data for python that comes from a GET in API FLASK like JSON, for some reason when python will insert this data or maybe postgres itself, it is removing the `000000`

**Data json:**

```
{
"datecollect": 1585983000000
}
```

**Insert py:**

```
    conn.execute('''INSERT INTO "TBLNAME"
    (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
    VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}',to_timestamp({3}) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',current_timestamp)'''.
    format(server,forecastmemory,levelerror,datecollect))
```

**Original date:**

```
select to_timestamp(1585983000000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' --> 52227-10-20 17:20:00
```

**Date that python is inserting to pgsql:**

```
select to_timestamp(1585983) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' --> 1970-01-19 08:33:03
```

**Conversion correct:**

[image]

Even using the website's timezone, it returns with a problem `select to_timestamp(1585983000000) AT TIME ZONE 'GMT-03:00' --> 52227-10-20 20:20:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp value (`datecollect`) is apparently in milliseconds; you just need to divide it by 1000 to convert it from milliseconds to seconds:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1585983000000/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Output:

```
2020-04-04 06:50:00
```

So for your query:

```
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO "TBLNAME"
(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}',to_timestamp({3}) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',current_timestamp)'''.
format(server,forecastmemory,levelerror,datecollect/1000))
```